# hibernate "where" query only works for id field

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have a problem with a Hibernate query that looks as follows:

```
List persons = getList("FROM creator.models.Person p WHERE p.lastName="+userName);
```

(the `getList(String queryString)` method just executes the query using a session factory.)

This is my person class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="persons")
public class Person{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long        id;

    @Column(name="first_name", nullable=false, updatable=true)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name", nullable=false, updatable=true)
    private String lastName;
    /// etc
```

And this is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE persons(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name CHAR(50),
    last_name CHAR(50),
    abbreviation CHAR(4),

    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Searching for a person with the name TestName, I get an exception with this message:

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Unknown column 'TestName' in 'where clause'
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
//etc
```

The query created by Hibernate looks like this:

```
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Hibernate: select person0_.id as id8_, person0_.abbreviation as abbrevia2_8_, person0_.first_name as first3_8_, person0_.last_name as last4_8_ from persons person0_ where person0_.last_name=TestName
Dec 10, 2012 5:14:26 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
```

Searching for the id (`...`WHERE p.id`="3"`) works fine, by the way!

I hope somebody knows what is going wrong because for me the query looks right and I can't find out why the lastName is seen as a column name suddenly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to wrap your parameter with single quotes:

```
List persons = getList("FROM creator.models.Person p WHERE p.lastName='"+userName+"'");
```

but much better with a parameterized query:

```
        String hql = "FROM creator.models.Person p WHERE p.lastName= :userName";
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        query.setString("userName",userName);
        List results = query.list();
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to put userName in quotes:

```
"FROM creator.models.Person p WHERE p.lastName='"+userName+"'";
```

Or (which is much better) to use parameters

Answer (score 3):

replace your hql with:

```
    Query query = session.createQuery("from creator.models.Person p where p.lastName = ?")
       .setParameter(0, userName);
    List persons = query.list();
```

that way you also prevent sql-injection.